# Document.getelementbyId returns null when searching for div id

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, listview

I am currently trying to show two scroll bars, one at the top and one at the bottom of a ListView. However, my document.getelementbyid keeps returning null and I cant figure out why. I am also using a master page if that helps.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DoubleScroll(element1) {
        var element = document.getElementById(element1);
        if (!element) return;
        var scrollbar = document.createElement('div');
        scrollbar.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        scrollbar.style.overflow = 'auto';
        scrollbar.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
        scrollbar.style.width = '500px';
        scrollbar.firstChild.style.width = element.scrollWidth + 'px';
        scrollbar.firstChild.style.paddingTop = '100px';
        scrollbar.firstChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\xA0'));
        scrollbar.onscroll = function () {
            element.scrollLeft = scrollbar.scrollLeft;
        };
        element.onscroll = function () {
            scrollbar.scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft;
        };
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(scrollbar, element);
    }


    DoubleScroll(document.getElementById('doublescroll'));
</script>
```

Here is the div id I am trying to reach:

```
<div id="doublescroll" style=" width: 100%; height: auto;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PitaJ has one thing right, you are trying to use a DOM reference as an id. If you want it to be overloaded, you can always do a type check.

```
function DoubleScroll(element1) {
    var element = typeof element1 === "string" ? document.getElementById(element1) : element1;
```

Another problem might be the fact you are calling the element BEFORE it is rendered on the page. You can not reference an element before it exists.

Move the line `DoubleScroll(document.getElementById('doublescroll'));` to the bottom of the body, call it onload, or on document ready.

Comment: Ok so I created  $(document).ready(function(){
            DoubleScroll('doublescroll');
            
        } However, where do I place it? In my script tag?

Comment: Anywhere on the page.

Comment: I had to place it within the asp.net script tag but it works now!

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `document.getElementById` twice: once in the function argument and again inside the function. Remove one of these and it should work.

Comment: Thanks this fixed part of my question

Answer (score 1):

You are getting NULL because element1 is an object. When you call document.getElementById inside of the DoubleScroll function, is returns null because getElementById cannot accept an object as a parameter.

Here is how you should set element equal to element1:

```
        var element = element1;
```

You can find a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtruty/Bx2JL/1/

All that being said, it is redundant to set element = element1. Why not just use the object you are passing in?

Hope this help!